# How to generate unique string id from given array of strings in smart contract?

Tags: smart-contract, action

I am writing an **EOS** **smart contract** in which need to write the action to generate a unique id from the given array. Array consisting of n number of string elements (UUID). Suppose I pass 10 strings to generate one unique id and vice versa. Id can also be UUID. I am trying sha256 but not confirmed. Can you please suggest me the ways to do this? I am not getting the exact logic behind for generating id. And also how to generate UUID in a smart contract?

Comment: What's the problem with sha256 or something similar?

Comment: I am not getting how to pass this dynamic array to sha256. Use each array element to generate a single ID.

Comment: Can you post parts of your code?